# When I append items to a 2d list, it doesn't add to the same list

Tags: python, class, data-structures, priority-queue

```
class PriorityQueue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.q = []

    def enqueue(self, priority, item):
        self.q.append([priority, item])
        self.q = sorted(self.q)
        return self.q


x = PriorityQueue()
print(x.enqueue(3, "Potato"))

y = PriorityQueue()
print(y.enqueue(1, "Egg"))
```

I'm trying to do a priority list but it won't sort.

output;

```
[[3, 'Potato']]
[[1, 'Egg']]
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 2):

You are always creating a new `PriorityQueue`, I guess you want to have one queue:

```
class PriorityQueue:

    def __init__(self):
        self.q = []

    def enqueue(self, priority, item):
        self.q.append([priority, item])
        self.q = sorted(self.q)
        return self.q


y = PriorityQueue()
print(y.enqueue(3, "Egg"))
print(y.enqueue(4, "Potato"))
print(y.enqueue(2, "Chesse"))
print(y.enqueue(1, "Cake"))
```

Out:

```
[[3, 'Egg']]
[[3, 'Egg'], [4, 'Potato']]
[[2, 'Cheese'], [3, 'Egg'], [4, 'Potato']]
[[1, 'Cake'], [2, 'Cheese'], [3, 'Egg'], [4, 'Potato']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 separate objects. And you are enqueing in those two objects. That's why you get separate queues nothing surprising here.

```
class PriorityQueue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.q = []

    def enqueue(self, priority, item):
        self.q.append([priority, item])
        self.q.sort(key=lambda x:x[0])
        return self.q


x = PriorityQueue()
print(x.enqueue(3, "Potato"))
print(x.enqueue(1, "Egg"))
```

Output:

```
[[3, 'Potato']]
[[1, 'Egg'], [3, 'Potato']]
```

You are sorting the list again and again. This is not the right way to implement priority queue. The better way would be to use a heap.

Here is a sample example:

```
import heapq
h = []
h.append([3, "Potato"])
h.append([1, "Egg"])

heapq.heapify(h)
print(h)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 'Egg'], [3, 'Potato']]
```

To pop from the heap you would use `heapq.heappop(h)` etc. Check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) for further info.

Answer (score 0):

In this code you have a Class -> `PriorityQueue` which inherits a list `"q"`.
Now the code creates two Objects of Type `PriorityQueue`  x and y who are independent from each other.
This also means that their respective list `"q"` are independent from each other.

Test out the code below. It will make the entire process more vivid

```
class PriorityQueue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.q = []

    def enqueue(self, priority, item):
        self.q.append([priority, item])
        self.q = sorted(self.q)
        return self.q


grocerys = PriorityQueue()
print(grocerys.enqueue(3, "Potato"))
print(grocerys.enqueue(6, "Milk"))
print(grocerys.enqueue(1, "Egg"))

print("this is your grocery.q list", grocerys.q)

media = PriorityQueue()
print(media.enqueue(1, "PC"))
print(media.enqueue(3, "Television"))
print(media.enqueue(2, "Moonboard"))
print("this is your media.q list", media.q)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class PriorityQueue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def size(self):
        return len(self.items)

    def enqueue(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)
        self.items.sort()

    def dequeue(self):
        if self.size() == 0:
            return None
        return self.items.pop(0)


    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{[item for item in self.items]}"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = PriorityQueue()
    q.enqueue([3, "Potato"])
    q.enqueue([1, "Egg"])

    print(q)

    item_to_process = q.dequeue()
    print(item_to_process)
```

result

```
[[1, Egg], [3, Potato]]

[1, 'Egg']
```